# Getting the PDF from the Gausian Mixture Model in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scikit-learn

I have fit a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) to a data series that I have. Using GMM, I am trying to get the probabilities of another vector, element-wise. Matlab achieves this with the following lines of code.

```
a = reshape(0:1:15, 14, 1);
gm = fitgmdist(a, 13);  % 13 specifies the number of components (means and covs for example) in the fit model

% Testing with new data
b = reshape(-5:1:5, 11, 1);
pdf(gm, b) 

    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0018
    0.0643
    0.0658
    0.0671
    0.0666
    0.0662
    0.0672
```

This is expected because the negative values `-5` through `0` are not present in the data provided while fitting and therefore provide near zero values.

I am trying to replicate this using python with `sklearn`. Following is what I have achieved so far.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np

gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=13).fit(np.arange(16).reshape(-1, 1))

# Generate test data
b = np.arange(-5, 6)[:, None]
prob = gm.predict_proba(b).tolist()

"""
prob=
[[8.539939840944505e-152, 0.0, 1.9638856033086253e-68, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[2.238593143299414e-141, 0.0, 3.166463050557315e-63, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[5.868073258732079e-131, 0.0, 5.106947259415683e-58, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[1.5382109014584666e-120, 0.0, 8.239047963148164e-53, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[4.0321459413005606e-110, 0.0, 1.3296012030592655e-47, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[8.790691487706948e-139, 0.0, 1.7850932827696813e-81, 8.316994953954272e-40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[6.040819196361928e-118, 0.0, 7.556403579572576e-66, 2.180313173877784e-29, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
[7.616317001277741e-99, 0.0, 5.870491452246584e-52, 1.0486913731065672e-20, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[1.761856615767359e-81, 0.9999999999999076, 8.370258307836422e-40, 9.254498458447064e-14, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[7.477776611058069e-66, 0.0, 2.190323924113167e-29, 1.4984230843298664e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9999999850157694, 0.0, 0.0], 
[5.823053603579932e-52, 0.0, 1.0519204995101235e-20, 4.4513567127132954e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9999554864328727, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
"""
```

The array `prob` returns a matrix in which each row signifies the probability of belonging to one of the `n_components` number of classes (implying sum along row = 1). This is however not the expected result. I would want to know the probability of each element of `b` being generated from the fit `gm` model, like Matlab does.

How can I achieve this through Python? Thanks.

Comment: I **think** (could be wrong) your understanding of what the number 13 is doing here, both in matlab code and as well in sklearns code is a bit flawed. After going through the docs, in essence the number 13 where you have used here is conveying the model to find 13 distinct Gaussian Distributions in the 16 1-D data samples that you are giving to the model.

Comment: Isn't it what the OP has described? I mean, i didn't get how your understanding is different from OP's.

Comment: @sai, that is true. I do not have any problem with fitting GMM in both these languages. For instance, the means in both the languages is a `13x1` vector. My question has got to do with the next step. I want an element-wise PDF from the fit `gm` model, which Matlab provides, in Python. I hope my intentions are clear this time around.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict_proba` finds the probability that the individual data row is assigned to each of component the GMM is based on (in your case, 13 components). For more, see Jake VanderPlas' [excellent chapter](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html).

To get the pdf, you'll need to use the [`score_samples`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.score_samples) function-which returns the weighted log probability that each row would be drawn from the fitted GMM:

```py
b = np.arange(-5, 6)[:, None]
log_probs = gm.score_samples(b)
sum_of_scores = (np.exp(log_probs)).sum()
probs = np.exp(log_probs) / sum_of_scores
print('Probs sum: ', probs.sum()) # confirm sums to 1
print('pdf: ', probs.tolist())
```

Note that in this toy example, due to the non-deterministic nature of the K-Means clustering at the initial part of the GMM fit algorithm, you most likely will not reproduce the exact results from matlab, but if you do have a more realistic, diverse, well sampled dataset to cross-check against the MATLAB implementation, they will agree much better.

Comment: So you're suggesting a `softmax` to normalize it?

Comment: Yes that’s right, softmax, because it’s a LogLikelihood